# get a field in a object in db4o in java

Tags: java, db4o

i have a query method. i use db40 in java

```
public static void checkQuery(ObjectContainer db, final String nameFish) {
    ObjectSet result = db.query(new Predicate<WaterFish>() {

        @Override
        public boolean match(WaterFish fish) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return fish.getGeneral_information().getVietnamese_name()
                    .contains("Ông tiên");
        }
    });
    listResult(result);

}
```

result contains : fish{nameFish, distribution} and image.
how i can get only nameFish field in fish object
how i can get a only field in result ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

db4o (at least until Jan/2012) can only load full objects. You can use some tricks like introduce a new class to hold data (fields) that you don't use very often and rely on [transparent activation](http://community.versant.com/documentation/Reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/basics/transparent_persistence.htm) to load this data when required (something like the code below).

```
class FishData
{
   private Image picture;

   // other fields, getters / setters etc
}

class Fish
{
   private string name;
   private FishData data;

   // other fields, getters / setters etc  
}
```